# Apache Lucene TokenStream contract violation

Tags: java, lucene

Using Appache Lucene TokenStream to remove stopwords 
causes an error:

```
TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
```

I use this code:

```
public static String removeStopWords(String string) throws IOException {
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, new StringReader(string));
    TokenFilter tokenFilter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenStream);
    TokenStream stopFilter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenFilter, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    while(stopFilter.incrementToken()) {
        if(stringBuilder.length() > 0 ) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        stringBuilder.append(token.toString());
    }

    stopFilter.end();
    stopFilter.close();

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

But as you can see i never call reset() or close().

So why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i never call reset() or close().

Well, that *is* your problem. If you care to read `TokenStream` javadoc, you would find the following:

> The workflow of the new `TokenStream` API is as follows:
>
> 1. Instantiation of `TokenStream`/`TokenFilter`s which add/get attributes to/from the `AttributeSource`.
> 2. The consumer calls `TokenStream#reset()`
> 3. ...

I only had to add one line with `reset()` to your code and it worked.

```
...    
CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
tokenStream.reset();   // I added this 
while(stopFilter.incrementToken()) {
...
```

Comment: Well... I have that single line, and I still get this error :)

Comment: Same issue even if calling reset

Comment: I believe we should add also stream.close() after while loop. Otherwise, we get this error 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: close() call missing'

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error when reuse the same Tokenizer.
The reason just in the comments.
The solution is set a new reader or create a new Tokenizer.

```java
  /** Expert: Set a new reader on the Tokenizer.  Typically, an
   *  analyzer (in its tokenStream method) will use
   *  this to re-use a previously created tokenizer. */
  public final void setReader(Reader input) {
    if (input == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("input must not be null");
    } else if (this.input != ILLEGAL_STATE_READER) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("TokenStream contract violation: close() call missing");
    }
    this.inputPending = input;
    setReaderTestPoint();
  }
```