# Error in Keyword extraction using lucene

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, feature-extraction

I'm completely new to the text extraction concept. When I was searching for an example I found one which has implemented using Lucene. I just tried to run it in eclipse but it gave an error. This is the error I'm getting : (TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow). I directly get the code form a published article on the web and did few modifications because first I wanted to make sure that the code is running without error before understanding it's parts one by one. The original code was getting text from an URL but I changed it to get texts from a defined String (It's in the main method). I also changed the version since I'm using lucene 4.8 version.

I also searched the error and did few modifications but still I'm getting the error. I the code here. Could you please help me to get rid of this error. Where should I modify to avoid the error. This is the link where I get the code http://pastebin.com/jNALz7DZ Here is the code I modified.

```
public class KeywordsGuesser {

     /** Lucene version. */
     private static Version LUCENE_VERSION = Version.LUCENE_48;

     /**
      * Keyword holder, composed by a unique stem, its frequency, and a set of found corresponding
      * terms for this stem.
      */
    public static class Keyword implements Comparable<Keyword> {

         /** The unique stem. */
         private String stem;

         /** The frequency of the stem. */
         private Integer frequency;

         /** The found corresponding terms for this stem. */
        private Set<String> terms;

         /**
          * Unique constructor.
          * 
          * @param stem The unique stem this instance must hold.
          */
         public Keyword(String stem) {
             this.stem = stem;
            terms = new HashSet<String>();
             frequency = 0;
         }

         /**
          * Add a found corresponding term for this stem. If this term has been already found, it
          * won't be duplicated but the stem frequency will still be incremented.
          * 
          * @param term The term to add.
          */
         private void add(String term) {
             terms.add(term);
             frequency++;
         }

         /**
          * Gets the unique stem of this instance.
          * 
          * @return The unique stem.
          */
         public String getStem() {
             return stem;
         }

         /**
          * Gets the frequency of this stem.
          * 
          * @return The frequency.
          */
         public Integer getFrequency() {
             return frequency;
         }

         /**
          * Gets the list of found corresponding terms for this stem.
          * 
          * @return The list of found corresponding terms.
          */
        public Set<String> getTerms() {
             return terms;
         }

         /**
          * Used to reverse sort a list of keywords based on their frequency (from the most frequent
          * keyword to the least frequent one).
          */
         @Override
         public int compareTo(Keyword o) {
             return o.frequency.compareTo(frequency);
         }

         /**
          * Used to keep unicity between two keywords: only their respective stems are taken into
          * account.
          */
         @Override
         public boolean equals(Object obj) {
             return obj instanceof Keyword && obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
         }

         /**
          * Used to keep unicity between two keywords: only their respective stems are taken into
          * account.
          */
         @Override
         public int hashCode() {
             return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { stem });
         }

         /**
          * User-readable representation of a keyword: "[stem] x[frequency]".
          */
         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return stem + " x" + frequency;
         }

     }

     /**
      * Stemmize the given term.
      * 
      * @param term The term to stem.
      * @return The stem of the given term.
      * @throws IOException If an I/O error occured.
      */
     private static String stemmize(String term) throws IOException {

         // tokenize term
         TokenStream tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader(term));
         // stemmize
         tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);

         Set<String> stems = new HashSet<String>();
         CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
         // for each token
         while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
             // add it in the dedicated set (to keep unicity)
             stems.add(token.toString());
         }

         // if no stem or 2+ stems have been found, return null
         if (stems.size() != 1) {
             return null;
         }

         String stem = stems.iterator().next();

         // if the stem has non-alphanumerical chars, return null
         if (!stem.matches("[\\w-]+")) {
             return null;
         }

         return stem;
     }

     /**
      * Tries to find the given example within the given collection. If it hasn't been found, the
      * example is automatically added in the collection and is then returned.
      * 
      * @param collection The collection to search into.
      * @param example The example to search.
      * @return The existing element if it has been found, the given example otherwise.
      */
     private static <T> T find(Collection<T> collection, T example) {
         for (T element : collection) {
             if (element.equals(example)) {
                 return element;
             }
         }
         collection.add(example);
         return example;
     }

     /**
      * Extracts text content from the given URL and guesses keywords within it (needs jsoup parser).
      * 
      * @param The URL to read.
      * @return A set of potential keywords. The first keyword is the most frequent one, the last the
      *         least frequent.
      * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurred.
      * @see <a href="http://jsoup.org/">http://jsoup.org/</a>
      */
     public static List<Keyword> guessFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
         // get textual content from url
         //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         //String content = doc.body().text();

       String content = url;
         // guess keywords from this content
         return guessFromString(content);
     }

     /**
      * Guesses keywords from given input string.
      * 
      * @param input The input string.
      * @return A set of potential keywords. The first keyword is the most frequent one, the last the
      *         least frequent.
      * @throws IOException If an I/O error occured.
      */
     public static List<Keyword> guessFromString(String input) throws IOException {

         // hack to keep dashed words (e.g. "non-specific" rather than "non" and "specific")
         input = input.replaceAll("-+", "-0");
         // replace any punctuation char but dashes and apostrophes and by a space
         input = input.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]]+", " ");
         // replace most common English contractions
         input = input.replaceAll("(?:'(?:[tdsm]|[vr]e|ll))+\\b", "");

         // tokenize input
         TokenStream tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader(input));
         // to lower case
         tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream);
         // remove dots from acronyms (and "'s" but already done manually above)
         tokenStream = new ClassicFilter(tokenStream);
         // convert any char to ASCII
         tokenStream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tokenStream);
         // remove english stop words
         tokenStream = new StopFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());

         List<Keyword> keywords = new LinkedList<Keyword>();
         CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

         // for each token
         while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
             String term = token.toString();
             // stemmize
             String stem = stemmize(term);
             if (stem != null) {
                 // create the keyword or get the existing one if any
                 Keyword keyword = find(keywords, new Keyword(stem.replaceAll("-0", "-")));
                 // add its corresponding initial token
                 keyword.add(term.replaceAll("-0", "-"));
             }
         }



         tokenStream.end();
         tokenStream.close();


         // reverse sort by frequency
         Collections.sort(keywords);

         return keywords;
     }



     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

       String input = "Java is a computer programming language that is concurrent, "
               + "class-based, object-oriented, and specifically designed to have as few "
               + "implementation dependencies as possible. It is intended to let application developers "
               + "write once, run anywhere (WORA), "
               + "meaning that code that runs on one platform does not need to be recompiled "
               + "to run on another. Java applications are typically compiled to byte code (class file) "
               + "that can run on any Java virtual machine (JVM) regardless of computer architecture. "
               + "Java is, as of 2014, one of the most popular programming languages in use, particularly "
               + "for client-server web applications, with a reported 9 million developers."
               + "[10][11] Java was originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems "
               + "(which has since merged into Oracle Corporation) and released in 1995 as a core "
               + "component of Sun Microsystems' Java platform. The language derives much of its syntax "
               + "from C and C++, but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them."
               + "The original and reference implementation Java compilers, virtual machines, and "
               + "class libraries were developed by Sun from 1991 and first released in 1995. As of "
               + "May 2007, in compliance with the specifications of the Java Community Process, "
               + "Sun relicensed most of its Java technologies under the GNU General Public License. "
               + "Others have also developed alternative implementations of these Sun technologies, "
               + "such as the GNU Compiler for Java (byte code compiler), GNU Classpath "
               + "(standard libraries), and IcedTea-Web (browser plugin for applets).";

       System.out.println(KeywordsGuesser.guessFromString(input));
     }



 }
```

This is the error outputted by eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer$1.read(Tokenizer.java:110)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(ClassicTokenizerImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(ClassicTokenizerImpl.java:638)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicTokenizer.incrementToken(ClassicTokenizer.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicFilter.incrementToken(ClassicFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.ASCIIFoldingFilter.incrementToken(ASCIIFoldingFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:82)
    at beehex.lucene.KeywordsGuesser.guessFromString(KeywordsGuesser.java:239)
    at beehex.lucene.KeywordsGuesser.main(KeywordsGuesser.java:288)
```

After get rid of the error my output is:

> [java x10, develop x5, sun x5, run x4, compil x4, languag x3,
>   implement x3, applic x3, code x3, gnu x3, comput x2, program x2,
>   specif x2, have x2, on x2, platform x2, byte x2, class x2, virtual x2,
>   machin x2, most x2, origin x2, microsystem x2, ha x2, releas x2, 1995
>   x2, it x2, from x2, c x2, librari x2, technolog x2, concurr x1,
>   class-bas x1, object-ori x1, design x1, few x1, depend x1, possibl x1,
>   intend x1, let x1, write x1, onc x1, anywher x1, wora x1, mean x1, doe
>   x1, need x1, recompil x1, anoth x1, typic x1, file x1, can x1, ani x1,
>   jvm x1, regardless x1, architectur x1, 2014 x1, popular x1, us x1,
>   particularli x1, client-serv x1, web x1, report x1, 9 x1, million x1,
>   10 x1, 11 x1, jame x1, gosl x1, which x1, sinc x1, merg x1, oracl x1,
>   corpor x1, core x1, compon x1, deriv x1, much x1, syntax x1, fewer x1,
>   low-level x1, facil x1, than x1, either x1, them x1, refer x1, were
>   x1, 1991 x1, first x1, mai x1, 2007 x1, complianc x1, commun x1,
>   process x1, relicens x1, under x1, gener x1, public x1, licens x1,
>   other x1, also x1, altern x1, classpath x1, standard x1, icedtea-web
>   x1, browser x1, plugin x1, applet x1]

Comment: please print the exact stacktrace as outputted by your IDE

Comment: Thanks for your kind corporation but, Sorry your idea is not clear to me. What Should I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appache Lucene TokenStream contract violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931699/appache-lucene-tokenstream-contract-violation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the `TokenStream` object before you call the `incrementToken` method on it, as the error points out :

```
// add this line
tokenStream.reset();
while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
....
```

Comment: Thank you Very much. I'm getting the out put. I referred this post published on stackoverflow site as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447045/java-library-for-keywords-extraction-from-input-text Is there any way to display the output as mentioned in this post ? And I modified my main method into System.out.println(KeywordsGuesser.guessFromString(input));

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the lucene demo module : http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/demo/overview-summary.html if you want to learn more about lucene, or just grab an information retrieval book and read that if you want to learn about inverted indexes, stemming etc...